# Maya: Get/Set vertex Normal in world space?

Tags: python, pivot, maya, normals

i'm working on small tool which bake custom pivot.Sounds like nothing special.
The thing is when I run comand `bakeCustomPivot`, it also brakes custom normals which must keep their orientation all time in my case. The first idea that came into mind is to save vertices normal before bake and restore them after they have changed.But now I have real problem.

`cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalX=1)` returns values which are equal to values I got after pivot was baket since normals change their orientation   with object pivot orientation in same way.

My step was to get difference beetwen pivot orientation before and after pivot bake and next step is to add this difference to normal value. Unfortunatelly it did not help.

So after short brainstorm I decided to try another way and get vertex normal value in world space directly.

Actually this is where by brainstorm stopped)

This will help to undrestand more clearly what I mean. Just run it

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

# create test plane
plane = cmds. polyPlane(axis=[0,0,1], subdivisionsHeight=2, subdivisionsWidth=2)
cmds.select(plane[0]+'.vtx[*]')
objVertices = cmds.ls(sl=1,fl=1)


# Activate normals preview
cmds.select(plane)
mel.eval('ToggleVertexNormalDisplay')

# Change plane normals to any
cmds.polyNormalPerVertex(objVertices, normalXYZ=[0.3, 0.4, 1.0])

# get vtx normal vector for one vtx before bake
cmds.select(objVertices[0])
oldVtxNormalX = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalX=1)
oldVtxNormalY = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalY=1)
oldVtxNormalZ = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalZ=1)
oldVtxValue = list(map(lambda x: x[0], [oldVtxNormalX] + [oldVtxNormalY] + [oldVtxNormalZ]))

# Warning. Why values are differ from custom values? They are smaller
print ( '{} --------- Old normal value '.format(oldVtxValue) ) # [0.26832816004753113, 0.3577708899974823, 0.8944271802902222]


# Rotate pivot, bake it (Modify/Bake Pivot)
cmds.select(plane)
cmds.manipPivot(o=[45.0, 0.0, 0.0])  # apply pivot
mel.eval('BakeCustomPivot')


# get vtx normal vector for one vtx after bake
cmds.select(objVertices[0])
newVtxNormalX = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalX=1)
newVtxNormalY = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalY=1)
newVtxNormalZ = cmds.polyNormalPerVertex( q=1, normalZ=1)
newVtxValue = list(map(lambda x: x[0], [newVtxNormalX] + [newVtxNormalY] + [newVtxNormalZ]))
print ( '{} --------- New normal value after bake. Same result '.format(newVtxValue) ) # [0.26832816004753113, 0.3577708899974823, 0.8944271802902222]

# !!!! As you can see normal values still same despite of fact pivot have changed
```

Comment: Normals are [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), their length is always 1.0. When you set the normals to `[0.3, 0.4, 1.0]`, that value gets _normalized_, resulting in `[0.26832816, 0.35777088, 0.89442718]` (rounded).

Answer (score 0):

The polyNormalPerVertex cmd returns the values in objectspace. And baking the pivot sets the pivot to 0 but the rotation of the object to 45 degree. If you set the rotation to 0, the normals point exactly in the same direction.

Comment: Hi! I think I didn`t catch the part when exactly do i need to set rotation to 0, before or after baking? Could you please clarify?
This is how I understood you comment.
First I set rotation foк custom pivot as I wish, next I rotate object -45 degree in order to compensate custom pivot rotataion and only then I ask maya to bake custom pivot and this  must help me keep original normal direction. I have tried, no luck)

Comment: What I want to say is that the BakeCustomPivot simply sets the pivot to 0 but sets the object rotation to the value which was in custom pivot before. This means there is no change in normals in object space.